# androidx.test.espresso.NoMatchingViewException: No views in hierarchy found matching

Tags: android, kotlin, android-espresso, android-testing

I'm trying to test my fragment with Espresso. No matter what view I'm trying to test I get `NoMatchingViewException`, I'm 100% sure that the view actually exists on the fragment.
This is my test:

```kotlin
@LargeTest
@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class ExploreFragmentTest {
    private lateinit var blogRepository: FakeBlogRepository
    private lateinit var inAppMessagesRepository: FakeInAppMessageRepository
    private lateinit var fakeFarRetailsRepository: FakeFarRetailsRepository
    private lateinit var fakeUserProfileRepository: FakeUserProfileRepository

    @Before
    fun initRepository() {
        blogRepository = FakeBlogRepository()
        inAppMessagesRepository = FakeInAppMessageRepository()
        fakeFarRetailsRepository = FakeFarRetailsRepository()
        fakeUserProfileRepository = FakeUserProfileRepository()

        ServiceLocator.blogRepository = blogRepository
        ServiceLocator.inAppMessagesRepository = inAppMessagesRepository
        ServiceLocator.userProfileRepository = fakeUserProfileRepository
    }

    @Test
    fun noRetailsNearby_displaysNoRetailsNearbyLayout() = runBlockingTest {
        // GIVEN - A fake repository with far retails
        ServiceLocator.retailsRepository = fakeFarRetailsRepository
        // WHEN - ExploreFragment launched to display retails
        launchFragmentInContainer<ExploreFragment>(null, R.style.AppTheme)
        // THEN - No retails layout is displayed on the screen
        onView(withId(R.id.clExploreContainer)).check(matches(isDisplayed()))
    }
}
```

This is the layout of the related fragment:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@id/clExploreContainer"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/ablExplore"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/toolbar_height"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:id="@+id/ctlExploreHeader"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
                app:statusBarScrim="@android:color/transparent"
                app:toolbarId="@+id/tbExplore">

            <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/ivHeaderLemon"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:src="@drawable/bg_main"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/tbExplore"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/collapsed_toolbar_height"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                    android:id="@+id/collapsing_logo"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize">

                <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/ivLogo"
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/toolbar_logo_width"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/toolbar_logo_height"
                        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                        android:scaleType="fitStart"
                        android:src="@drawable/myfoody_logo"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:id="@+id/svExplore"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/clExploreContainer"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <include
                    android:id="@+id/miniInAppMessageLayout"
                    layout="@layout/mini_in_app_message_layout"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    tools:visibility="visible" />

            <include
                    android:id="@+id/tutorialLayout"
                    layout="@layout/tutorial_layout"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/miniInAppMessageLayout"
                    tools:visibility="visible" />

            <include
                    android:id="@+id/nearToMeLayout"
                    layout="@layout/near_to_me_layout"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tutorialLayout" />

            <include
                    android:id="@+id/favouritesLayout"
                    layout="@layout/favourites_layout"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/section_explore_margin_top"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/nearToMeLayout"
                    tools:visibility="visible" />

            <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
                    android:id="@+id/flCompanyMessageFragment"
                    android:name="com.anagramma.myfoody.fragments.explore.blog.RecipesFragment"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/section_explore_margin_top"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/favouritesLayout" />

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                    android:id="@+id/clRemoteMessagesContainer"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/flCompanyMessageFragment">

                <include
                        android:id="@+id/rcmlExplore"
                        layout="@layout/remote_config_message_layout_explore"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:visibility="gone"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                        tools:visibility="visible" />

                <include
                        android:id="@+id/lMeetMyBrandBannerExplore"
                        layout="@layout/meet_my_brand_banner"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/section_explore_margin_top"
                        android:visibility="gone"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

            <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
                    android:id="@+id/flLastArticles"
                    android:name="com.anagramma.myfoody.fragments.explore.blog.LastArticlesFragment"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/section_explore_margin_top"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/clRemoteMessagesContainer"
                    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_explore_blog_section" />

            <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
                    android:id="@+id/flLiveSustainable"
                    android:name="com.anagramma.myfoody.fragments.explore.blog.LiveSustainableFragment"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/section_explore_margin_top"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/flLastArticles"
                    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_explore_blog_section" />

            <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
                    android:id="@+id/flMyFoodyWorld"
                    android:name="com.anagramma.myfoody.fragments.explore.blog.MyFoodyWorldFragment"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/section_explore_margin_top"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/flLiveSustainable"
                    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_explore_blog_section" />

            <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
                    android:id="@+id/fAutoProduction"
                    android:name="com.anagramma.myfoody.fragments.explore.blog.AutoproductionFragment"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/section_explore_margin_top"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/flMyFoodyWorld"
                    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_explore_blog_section" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Every time I run the test I get this error: `androidx.test.espresso.NoMatchingViewException: No views in hierarchy found matching: with id: com.anagramma.myfoody.staging:id/clExploreContainer`, can't understand why. Am I missing something related to espresso framework?

Comment: I have the same problem, Espresso claiming that it can't find what Layout Inspector shows exists. I posted a bug report to Google. It seems that something is wrong that is out of our control. I will bookmark your question and post Google's reply, if any. It seems that we're dead in the water otherwise as my problem showed up in the automatically generated Android Studio example instrumented test.

Comment: @Jeff I've just posted an answer for that, don't know if it's your case too.

Comment: it doesn't look like they are the same. The widget that I refer to is in a menu in the Toolbar at the top of the Activity and set using setSupportActionBar, no fragments! I don't see anything in the Toolbar reference that would indicate that there might be a life cycle problem. Glad to see that you solved your problem though! Good job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem was that my fragment had a `DialogFragment` covering the entire original fragment view during its startup. Since DialogFragment has another lifecycle, my Espresso test wasn't finding any view on the parent fragment (`ExploreFragment`). Once removed the `DialogFragment` view matching turned out fine in my test.